# Net::SSH2 on higher ping networks

Tags: perl, ssh

It seems that reading from `<$chan>` gives empty list and it occurs mostly with hosts on higher latency networks. Is there more robust way of interacting with remote host?

```
use Net::SSH2;

# my $ssh = Net::SSH2->new();
# ...

my $chan = $ssh->channel() or die "no channel\n";
$chan->blocking(1); # even worse with $chan->blocking(0);
$chan->shell();

print $chan "ps -ef\n";
print <$chan>;
```

**EDIT:**

Error when using `Net::SSH::Any`,

> Can't call method "exec" on an undefined value at lib/Net/SSH/Any/Backend/Net_SSH2.pm line 133.

```
sub _capture {
    my ($any, $opts, $cmd) = @_;
    my $ssh2 = $any->{be_ssh2} or return;
    my $channel = $ssh2->channel;
    my ($out_fh, $err_fh) = __parse_fh_opts($any, $opts, $channel) or return;
    $out_fh and die 'Internal error: $out_fh is not undef';

    # vvvvvvvvvvvvvv
    $channel->exec($cmd); # <--- LINE 133
    # ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^

    (__io3($any, $ssh2, $channel, $opts->{stdin_data}, undef, $err_fh || \*STDERR))[0];
}
```

Comment: Talking to a remote shell via a Net::SSH2::Channel object is quite difficult. Try using [Net::SSH::Any](https://metacpan.org/module/Net::SSH::Any) instead.

Comment: @salva I'm considering switch to your `Net::OpenSSH` module. I guess `capture()` and `pipe_out()` works better?

Comment: They are easier to use, with [Net::SSH2](https://metacpan.org/module/Net::SSH2) you will have to write them yourself on top of low level primitives. The only real issue with [Net::OpenSSH](https://metacpan.org/module/Net::OpenSSH) is that it doesn't work on Windows.

Comment: @salva yes, i see it doesn't work on win32. btw, `Net::SSH2::Simple` looks interesting.

Comment: Looking at Net::SSH2::Simple source code I see it is quite buggy. For instance, it doesn't handle errors and time-outs don't work either.

Comment: And buggy it is; timeouts are no go, as you said. As for `Net::SSH::Any->new()`, do I have to check `$ssh->error` for errors?

Comment: Yes, the API is a subset of Net::OpenSSH. Also, the documentation has been greatly improved on the [development version at GitHub](https://github.com/salva/p5-Net-SSH-Any)

Comment: @salva should `my $channel = $ssh2->channel;` check for return value? I'm getting above error (post updated).

Comment: It should do but unfortunately I have not implemented time-out support on the Net::SSH2 back-end yet. It shouldn't be difficult, let me take a look...

Comment: Yes, a defined check is missing there.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [Net::SSH::Any](https://metacpan.org/module/Net%3a%3aSSH%3a%3aAny)!

A couple of days ago I released version 0.04 with fixes for the two problems we were talking about:

- the unchecked calls to `channel`
- timeout support on the `Net::SSH2` backend. It is still not perfect as neither OpenSSH, nor libssh2 support sending signals to the remote process in order to terminate it, so, the module just closes the stdio streams and hopes the remote program will eventually receive a SIGPIPE the next time it tries to write.

Comment: great, I'll try new version